# Função SE - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, funções, fórmula

Boa tarde!

Estou tendo dificuldade em como fazer um campo verdadeiro ou falso mas com 3 variaveis.

- Se A1 e B1 = "N" vai ser Nulo
- Se apenas A1 = "N" vai ser Verdadeiro
- Se Apenas B1 = "N" vai ser Falso

Como posso montar uma função no Excel baseado nisso ?

Estou usando a base de **=SE(E(A1="N"; Verdadeiro; Falso);**

Mas não consigo encaixar a terceira variavel se ambos for N

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [SES()](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/ses-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ses-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45) para criar múltiplas condicionais.

Então a seguinte fórmula pode ser criada, com três condições diferentes:

`=SES(E($A1="N";$B1="N");"";E($A1="N";$B1<>"N");VERDADEIRO;E($A1<>"N";$B1="N");FALSO)`

#### Resultado

O seguinte resultado é obtido inserindo a fórmula na coluna C:

```
|   | A | B |     C      |
|---|---|---|------------|
| 1 | N | N |            |
| 2 | N |   | VERDADEIRO |
| 3 |   | N | FALSO      |
```

Comment: Quando eu coloco essa formula está aparecendo o campo "#NOME?"

Comment: Verifique na documentação o que é este erro: [#NOME?](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/como-corrigir-um-erro-nome-b6d54e31-a743-4d7d-9b61-40002a7b4286) e veja se está tudo digitado corretamente na sua fórmula. As funções devem estar na linguagem do Office, por exemplo `SES` no Excel em inglês é `IFS`. Tente entender a fórmula da resposta e não só copiar tudo e colar.

Comment: Minha versão do pacote office é antigo e não tem a função SES(), irei atualizar, desde já muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Se sua versão do Office não dispõe da função SES tente:

```
=SE(E(A1="N"; B1="N"); ""; SE(A1="N"; Verdadeiro; SE(B1="N"; Falso; "Ambos diferentes de N")))
```

Considerando a possibilidade de ocorrer a última condição, se tal condição for impossível de ocorrer simplesmente troque o último SE por Falso.

Note que você diz que são com 3 variáveis mas em seu exemplo só constam 2: A1 e B1.